# Do I need coffee-rails, sass-rails, etc.. in Production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

Do I need to have:

`gem 'sass'`
`gem 'sass-rails'`
`gem 'coffee-rails'`

etc.. in my Gemfile for production? My knowledge of Rails and the asset pipeline is somewhat limited but I would think that these are only needed for creating assets one time, which could be done before pushing to production?

We are running Rails 4.2 + Puma hosted with Heroku.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you suggested, this depends on the way you do deployment. Heroku does asset compilation at deployment time so if you use Sass and CoffeeScript you will have to keep these gems in production environment as well.

Alternatively, it is possible to do asset compilation before deployment and only push compiled assets. This would require some amount of configuration and scripting though. In such a case those gems can be limited to development environment.